# extjs search box

Tags: search, extjs, autocomplete

I'm, trying to add a search box exactly as one on sencha docs home page http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

I used the code from the example 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/forum-search.html
and everything works as expected except for one thing ..

when I select an option from a list in my search box the combobox value is set to the selected value .. and when I press arrow down button it performs a new search with modified query .. 
but I just want to see the results of the previous search - exactly the behaviour of the search box on sencha page

any ideas how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need first sample from this page. Type "A" first
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/combos.html

Comment: thanks for the link , but is not quite what I'm after. what i need is that when i enter 'combo' in the search box on sencha I get a dropdown with 6 results, when I choose one - i get the page displayed, but the text in the search box is still 'combo'. and then i can press PAGE_DOWN and bring up the same 6 results .. anyway I've found  a way to do this .. will post the code in a minute

Comment: Just display results in separate container. IMHO: Do not complicate the program, use simple and standard behavior

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things the code below does what i need, but maybe there is a better way ..

I had to set  triggerAction to  'query' and also had to manually reset the text of the combobox in the the select event handler

```
var searchBox = {
      xtype: 'combo',
        store: dataStore,
        displayField: 'title',
        valueField: 'id',
        autoSelect: false,
        typeAhead: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Search for',
        hideTrigger:true,
        anchor: '100%',
        mode:'remote',
        triggerAction: 'query', 
        listeners: {
            'select' : function(combo) {
                var selected = this.value;
                combo.setValue(combo.lastQuery);
                showResult(selected);                   
            }
        },
        listConfig: {
            loadingText: 'Searching ...',
            emptyText: 'No matching posts found.',
            getInnerTpl: function() {
                return '<a class="search-item" href="?term={id}" onclick="return javascript:showResult(\'{id}\')">' +
                    '<h3><span>{title}<br /></span>{id}</h3></a>';
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    }
```